# Taking partial sums repeatedly to get to perfect powers.

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Let $S_{1,k}(n) = n,\  S_{i,k}(n) = \sum_{\text{n terms},(k-i+2)\nmid j} S_{i-1,k}(j)$

For example, $S_{1,2}(n) = n, S_{2,2}(n) = 1 + 3 + \dots+(2n-1) = n^2$

With $k=3$, take partial sums avoiding indices that are multiples of $3$ first and then partial sums avoiding indices that are multiples of 2. The final numbers are simply the cubes.

The general conjecture is that $S_{k,k}(n) = n^k$. There are more examples with details in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3csd2a/a_problem_i_have_been_thinking_about_lately/) reddit post.

I think I can prove it but it seems rather complicated and the result amazingly simple. Is there a simple proof for this fact, perhaps from the [theory of finite differences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference)?

Answer (score 0):

See my comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1681975/the-value-of-sum-k-0-infty-kn-xk/1682015#1682015). Specifically, we have that the generating function of $n^k$ is given by $$\operatorname{Li}_{-k}(z) = \sum_{j=0}^k S(k, j) z^j j! / (1-z)^{j+1}$$. This implies that $$n^k = \sum_{j=0}^k S(k, j) \binom{n}{j} j!  = \sum_{j=0}^k S(k, j) n! / (n-j)!,$$ 
which is a sum with $k$ terms each an integer multiple of a falling factorial function (finite, degree-$j$ polynomial in $n$). So we can write the perfect power as a sum of $k$ perfect powers each with predictable integer coefficients involving the Stirling numbers of both kinds: 
$$n^{k} = \sum_{m=0}^k\left(\sum_{j=0}^k S(k, j) s(j, m)\right) n^m.$$