# The value of $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n x^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Any known conclusions for $\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n x^k$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer and $0<x<1$?

- If $n=0$, the sum is simply $\frac{1}{1-x}$.
- If $n=1$, the sum can be computed as shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-infty-n1xn)
- For general $n$, it seems the method by taking derivative is
  extremely complicated though I believe the sum would have a
  finite value because $x^k$ decreases faster than $k^n$ increases.

Comment: Things like $\sum_k k^n$ doesnt have closed form for any n. Anyway exist a form to close it for any specific n through summation by parts, it is a "strong close" because you can use it for any partial sum, not only the infinite one. Check [this](https://www.cs.purdue.edu/homes/dgleich/publications/Gleich%202005%20-%20finite%20calculus.pdf).

Comment: Also discussed at this [MSE link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130184/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have a look at the following interesting reference, due to  Khristo N. Boyadzhiev, which adresses your issue:
[A series transformation formula and related polynomials](http://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijmms/2005/792107/abs/).

The author proved that

> $$
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n x^k=\frac1{1-x}\: \omega_n\!\left(\frac{x}{1-x}\! \right),\quad |x|<1,
> $$

where $\omega_n(\cdot)$ are the polynomials
$$
\omega_n(x)=\sum_0^n {\small{n\brace k}}k!\:x^k
$$ and where $\displaystyle {\small{n\brace k}}$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#Definition). One may notice that $\displaystyle {\small{n\brace k}}$  is the number of partitions of a set of $n$ elements into $k$ disjoint nonempty subsets.

Comment: Olivier, nice post, but the link is broken on the first embedded reference.  - Mark

Comment: @Dr.MV Edited. Thanks!

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for. It's a pity that the polynomial $w_n(x)$ is quite complicated. But I guess the solution couldn't be simpler.

Comment: Identities for these sums are given by the negative-order polylogarithm function, $\operatorname{Li}_{-n}$. Specific expansions in terms of the Stirling numbers of the second kind and first-order Eulerian numbers, $E_1(n,k)$, in *Concrete Mathematics* by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik: $\operatorname{Li}_{-n} = \sum_{j=0}^n S(n, j) z^j j! / (1-z)^{j+1} = \sum_{m=0}^n E_1(n, m) z^{m+1} / (1-z)^{n+1}$. For generalizations of this identity to forming generating functions for $\{j^n f_j\}_{j\geq0}$, see the proof in [this article](http://www.ilirias.com/jiasf/repository/docs/JIASF8-2-11.pdf) (2017).

Answer (score 5):

One can remark that $$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n x^k\right) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty k^{n+1} x^{k-1} = \frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^{n+1} x^{k}-1\right).$$ Hence, if we note $f_n(x) =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n x^k$, we find a relation $$xf'_n(x) = f_{n+1}(x)-1.$$ For example, we know that $f_0(x) = \frac{1}{1-x}$ and hence we find that $$f_1(x) = x \left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right)' +1 =\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}+1,$$ and so on.

Comment: Many thanks. I actually also noticed this method. The problem of this method is that the closed-form solution is not easy to obtain.

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't answer convergence, but a quick wolfram search gives:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html

$\sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n x^k = \Phi(x,-n,0)$

Answer (score 1):

Define for nonnegative integers $n$ the function  $$f_n(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_k(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty k^n z^k.$$  The ratio test shows that $$\left|\frac{a_{k+1}(z)}{a_k(z)}\right| = |z| \left(1 + \frac{1}{k}\right)^n,$$ and the limit as $k \to \infty$ for a fixed $n$ clearly shows that the function is absolutely convergent whenever $|z| < 1$, and divergent for $|z| > 1$.  The behavior for $|z| = 1$ is left to the reader to explore.

As for the sum itself, we observe $$f_{n+1}(z) = z \frac{d}{dz}[f_n(z)], \quad f_0(z) = (1-z)^{-1}$$ by formal differentiation of the power series.  This gives, for example $$\begin{align*} f_1(z) &= z(1-z)^{-2} \\ f_2(z) &= z(1+z)(1-z)^{-3} \\ f_3(z) &= z(1+4z+z^2)(1-z)^{-4} \\ f_4(z) &= z(1+z)(1+10z+z^2)(1-z)^{-5} \\ f_5(z) &= z(1+26z+66z^2+26z^3+z^4)(1-z)^{-6}. \end{align*}$$  This clearly suggests that $$f_{n+1}(z) = P_n(z) (1-z)^{-n}$$ for some suitable monic polynomial $P_n(z)$ with degree $n$ and integer coefficients, and that we should be interested in the coefficients of $P$; e.g., define $$P_n(z) = \sum_{m=0}^n c_{n,m} z^m.$$  Then we have the triangle of coefficients $$1 \\ 0, 1 \\ 0, 1, 1 \\ 0, 1, 4, 1 \\ 0, 1, 11, 11, 1 \\ 0, 1, 26, 66, 26, 1 $$ and so forth.  These happen to be [Eulerian numbers](https://oeis.org/A123125).  It is left as an exercise for the reader to prove various recursion relationships among these coefficients and that they satisfy the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any simple solutions for the general summation, but I do know a method that will work. Since $0 < x < 1$ let $x = \frac{1}{y}$ where $y > 1$. Consider $n = 2$
Let $S = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \frac{k^2}{y^k}$. 
\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{4}{y^2} + \frac{9}{y^3} + \frac{16}{y^4} + \cdots\\
\frac{S}{y} &= \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{4}{y^3} + \frac{9}{y^4} + \cdots\\
S - \frac{S}{y} = \frac{S(y - 1)}{y} &= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{3}{y^2} + \frac{5}{y^3} + \frac{7}{y^4} + \cdots\\
\frac{S(y - 1)}{y^2} &= \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{3}{y^3} + \frac{5}{y^4} + \cdots\\
\frac{S(y - 1)}{y} - \frac{S(y-1)}{y^2} = \frac{S(y-1)^2}{y^2} &= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{2}{y^2} + \frac{2}{y^3} + \frac{2}{y^4} + \cdots\\
&= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{2}{y^2}(1 + \frac{1}{y} + \frac{1}{y^2} + \cdots)\\
&= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{2}{y^2}(\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{y}}) = \frac{1}{y} + \frac{2}{y(y-1)}
\end{align}
Therefore $S = \frac{y^2}{(y-1)^2}(\frac{1}{y} + \frac{2}{y(y-1)}) = \frac{y}{(y-1)^2} + \frac{2y}{(y-1)^3}$. Now try this method for $n = 3$.
\begin{align}
S &= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{8}{y^2} + \frac{27}{y^3} + \frac{64}{y^4} + \cdots\\
\frac{S}{y} &= \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{8}{y^3} + \frac{27}{y^4} + \cdots \\
S - \frac{S}{y} = \frac{S(y-1)}{y} &= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{7}{y^2} + \frac{19}{y^3} + \frac{37}{y^4} + \cdots \\
\frac{S(y-1)}{y^2} &= \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{7}{y^3} + \frac{19}{y^4} + \cdots \\
\frac{S(y-1)^2}{y^2} &= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{6}{y^2} + \frac{12}{y^3} + \frac{18}{y^4} + \cdots\\
\frac{S(y-1)^2}{y^3} &= \frac{1}{y^2} + \frac{6}{y^3} + \frac{12}{y^4} + \cdots\\
\frac{S(y-1)^3}{y^3} &= \frac{1}{y} + \frac{5}{y^2} + \frac{6}{y^3} + \frac{6}{y^4} + \frac{6}{y^5} + \cdots
\end{align}
Which yields the geometric series. 
Basically the procedure consists of taking the difference between the sum and multiplying it by the common ratio $\frac{1}{y}$. This procedure will be done $n$ times in order to yield a finite amount of terms plus an infinite convergent geometric series. This occurs due to the property of finite differences. Quadratics have second differences, Cubics have third, $x^n$ has $n$ differences. This means the numerators eventually disappear into constants while the exponentials on the bottom remain the same. So just repeat this process $n$ times to compute the sum. This method only requires elementary algebra.